# Is there a plugin to encrypt data stored in WordPress?

Tags: encryption, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I am capturing information in a number of plugins (contact form 7, event espresso, etc) and I want to have that data saved into the CMS in an encrypted format. (Not hashing, which is one-way) I would then have the admin login and provide the password to decrypt that data (to be displayed in the CMS admin interface). How would I do this?

Comment: I don't think that - in general - data storage has been sufficiently abstracted to allow for an encryption layer to be added. Most of the time, libraries don't work that way. Maybe it would be possible to exchange the underlying database with one that performs encryption, but that does not sound easy (let alone that providers will offer such solutions). Even then, if the server is hacked, it would be easy for an attacker to intercept your password.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [mcrypt_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) while storing and [mcrypt_decrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) (with corresponding parameters) for reading data. It is really easy to use and straight forward - plus it is a battle-tested encryption package that has no (known) encryption flaws when used correctly.

Comment: I can do that but it requires altering the plugins in a custom way that may lead to problems. If there was an existing solution, I would prefer that.

Comment: There is no existing solution to automatically encrypt/decrypt arbitrary data from arbitrary ("etc") sources, as it would lead to a *lot* of prolems. The only way is to have your data storing- and retrieving parts of the code modified. As far as I know, no plugin would ever do that (and should never do that).

Comment: @bjoster battle tested maybe, but the wrapper itself contains a lot of indications that it was not written by an expert (providing an IV for ECB, bad naming of constants, no correct padding/unpadding, padding of keys and IV's, horrible example code, bad random number creation etc. etc. etc.) and I've seen no tests regarding buffer overruns etc. of the underlying C mcrypt library, which seems unmaintained at the moment - since 2007 no less.

Comment: @owlstead you are right. I still tend to recommend mcrypt, because it is well-documented, stable and used widely (in the projects I live in). But you are right, maybe [openssl_en/decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-encrypt.php) would be better alternative. Still not the solution to the 'just encrypt everything' problem, but there are better ways than mcrypt today. Take a sorry from an mcrypt oldtimer :-)